npm ci failing in github actions
I've setup github actions to run few checks (e.g. cspell) on the code before merging a pull request. However, now I'm facing an issue with the dependency installation step, I use clean install "npm ci" to install the dependencies but it fails, and I get this error:
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.

This issue happens only on github actions, I've tried replicating it in my local environment and it does happen, eventhough I'm running the same OS "Ubuntu" and the same node & npm versions.
What I tried:
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf packages/*/node_modules
npm cache clean --force
rm package-lock.json
npm install

It didn't work
This is one of the jobs that fails during the check
 lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Get checkout
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      # Install Node js
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.12.0'
          cache: 'npm'

      # Install Dependencies
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          npm ci

      # Run Linting
      - name: Run lint check
        run: |
          npm run check:lint



although this only circumvents the problem you can try an installation with less strict options like: npm install --legacy-pee-deps
If not I found this discussion which may help 
npm ci can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1
